# integrate by parts $\int x e^{\sec^2 x}\ (1+\tan^2x) \, dx$.

Tags: integration

i want to integrate $$\int x e^{\sec^2 x}\ (1+\tan^2x)\,dx.$$
I've tried using integration by parts and doesnt get the results. im stuck. anybody can help me ?
thankyou.

Comment: It should be \sec to get it right, actually \sec^2 . Next, I am guessing that the thing you have typed as tg^2 x is actually tangent squared, in which case it should be \tan^2 x

Comment: Worth remembering that $\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x) = \sec^2(x)$

Comment: I have tried and the result will appear integration by part on one side continuously.

Comment: What is $tg^2x$? EDIT: Ah I see now. Keep in mind that $1+\tan^2x$ is the same as $\sec^2x$

Comment: yah, tg is tan. thankyou for you correction.

Comment: I don't think this has an elementary solution. I tried it and some other things in Wolfram Alpha but to no avail.

Comment: i think so, but my lecturer requires to show the results and should use anti-derivative $ 1/D $ . not integration by part :(